# TypeError: List indices must be integer must be integer, not tuple

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find `first_row = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`

Currently, I have `list = [[1, a], [2, b], [3, c], [4, d], ...]`

and tried running: `list[:, 0]`

Output error: `TypeError: List indices must be integer must be integer, not tuple`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: ``list[:, 0]`` suggests you should be working with a ``numpy.array`` instead of the standard ``list`` type.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your question? Do you wonder why you get the error, or how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: It's a trick of Numpy that it "does the right thing" when the array index is a list.  In general, `list[:,0]` is interpreted as `list[(:, 0)]`, where the index is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks @FrankYellin  for interpretation of List[:,0]

Comment: I want to achieve the correct result and was trying to do this without extra for loop. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi for a correct interpretation, Your answer helped me.

Comment: The question might seem inappropriate, but many Python newbies will google this error after doing exactly the same thing. Hence I upvote the question (leaving aside that it might be a duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscript `lst[:,0]` does not do what you think it does. You might be used to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) or other libraries which support indexing in multidimensional matrices, but the builtin `list` does not support this.

Instead, you should use a list-comprehension.

```
first_row = [column[0] for column in lst]
```

This is a shorthand for the following more verbose expression.

```
first_row = []
for column in lst:
    first_row.append(lst[0])
```

In other words, you cannot *vectorize* multi-indexing with the `list` type. You have to recover each column one by one and the first element of each of those independently.

As a sidenote, try avoiding calling you variables `list` as it shadows the builtin of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

`list` doesn't support multiple (i.e. "comma-separated") indices, so you need something like

```
[sublist[0] for sublist in list]
```

The most popular alternative supporting multiple indexing like you tried is `numpy`'s [multidimensional array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html)

The reason why `list` cannot do this is because it is a general container, so it cannot imply what you store inside. You might have

```
values = [[1, 2], 'three', MyClass(4, 5, 6), None]
```

Applying `[0, :]` to this would make no sense, the same way as it doesn't in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
first_row = [i[0] for i in list]
```

Edit:
Since there are already two answers as this one, let me show a different one if you want to use slicing. First of all you SHOULDN'T use list as the name of your variable, since list is a reserved word in python. Suppose your list is called list1, you can do:

```
first_row = list(np.array(list1)[0,:].astype(int))
```